# JavaScript object coordinates not registering showing spotlight accurately on designated canvas

Tags: javascript, object, coordinates, javascript-objects

I'm currently taking a course on intro to computer programming. It's an online course and doesn't have much help when you're stuck.

I'm using Brackets and p5.js and I'm given a template to start off with. I seem to have done everything needed so far, but the spotlight isn't moving to the endX and endY coordinates.

I believe I haven't initialized the spotlight properly but I've tried multiple different ways. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

**Assignment Instructions:**
Edit the spotlight object by creating x and y properties initialized to your location. Also endX and endY properties initialized to Marvin's location

Make the spotlight move perfectly from you towards Marvin by adjusting the increments of the x and y properties. If you get everything correct then it will stop over the target.

Adjust x and y properties using

"+=" or "+"

"-=" or "-"
*/

**[Kindly see my code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yOIg.png)**:

Comment: Please do not post images of code/errors. Instead post the code/errors as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Java and javascript are different languages. Please remove the java tag.

Comment: Also post CODE. not PICTURES of code.